# Android http post + web service PHP

Tags: android, web-services, http-post

I have a web service in PHP which returns a String, he recives two parametres, id and te.
I've tested its using with the mozzila addon poster, so i decided to use it for my android app.

This is my android code:

```
final String query = null;

AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
RequestParams rp = new RequestParams();
rp.put("id", num);
rp.put("te", tab);
Log.i("http","before send\n");
client.post("http://appdomain.hol.es/webService.php",rp, new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){

    public void onSuccess(String jObject)
    {    
        query.replace(query, jObject);
Log.i("http","recived: "+jObject+"\n");

    }   
    public void onFailure(Throwable arg0)
    {
Log.i("http","fail");   
    }
});
```

I'm debugging whith log.i and i've could seen that it doesn't show neither recived neither fail.
can anyone helpl me?

PD: i leave the most relevant of webService

```
$id = $_POST["id"];
$te = $_POST["te"]; 
$query = "SELECT `preg` , `respA` , `respB` , `respC` , `respD` , `respV`FROM `".$te."` WHERE `id` =".$id;

$resultado= mysql_query($query,$link);
$arraySalida = array();
while($registro = mysql_fetch_assoc ($resultado) ):
    $cadena = "{$registro['preg']};{$registro['respA']};{$registro['respB']};{$registro['respC']};{$registro['respD']};{$registro['respV']}";
    $arraySalida[]= $cadena;

endwhile;
echo implode(":",$arraySalida);
```

the solution of @jaimin works but the compiler says: Type mismatch: cannot convert from AsyncTask to String in (!)

this is the code:

```
public String BBDD(int num, String tab)
    {
        HttpAsyncTask httpAsyncTask = new HttpAsyncTask(String.valueOf(num),tab);
        /*(!)*/String resul = httpAsyncTask.execute("http://opofire.hol.es/webServiceOpoFire.php");

        return resul;
}
```

Comment: whats is response type json or plan string?

Comment: @adcom String, if you want i can edit the post and write de webService code

Comment: do u wanna use AsyncHttpClient only?will any alternative code fine for you?

Comment: @adcom no, really anything that gets the string that the server send me worth me

Comment: i've used the code from @jaimin, thanks

Comment: for Type mismatch: u need to put value in class variable..String resul = httpAsyncTask.execute syntax is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for Http Post i'll suggest you to use AsyncTask<> which will run in separate thread from UI
here is the code i am using since two months and its working fine

```
 private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
 private String id,te;
 public  HttpAsyncTask(String id,String te){
        this.id = id;
        this.te = te;

    }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {



            return POST(urls[0]);
        }
        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
    }
public static String POST(String url){
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";
    try {

        // 1. create HttpClient
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        // 2. make POST request to the given URL
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
       // pass parameters in this way

       List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "value "));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("te", "value"));

    //add data
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        // 9. receive response as inputStream
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

        // 10. convert inputstream to string
        if(inputStream != null)
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        else
            result = "Did not work!";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
 // 11. return result
    return result;

}

private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        result += line;

    inputStream.close();
    return result;

}
```

for passing values you can create constructor like this.

form  your activity do this

```
 HttpAsyncTask httpAsyncTask = new HttpAsyncTask(id,te);//this will pass variables values 
 String  ResultfromServer = httpAsyncTask.execute(urlStr);// String ResultfromServer is your response string
```

and in AsyncTask I've created constructor

this is very helpful for me hope it will help you too

Comment: I've wrote this: HttpAsyncTask httpAsyncTask = new HttpAsyncTask(String.valueOf(numero),tab);
String resul = httpAsyncTask.execute("http://appdomin.hol.es/webService.php"); but the compiler says: Type mismatch: cannot convert from AsyncTask<String,Void,String> to String. what is the problem?

Comment: post your logcat in your question

Comment: is not possible to acces a this method: public static String POST(String url)? is not possible  access a this method: public static String POST(String url)? it return the result form the server

Comment: i can't post muy logcat because he doesn't let me to compile

Comment: wAIT LET ME HAVE A LOOK AGAIN

Comment: ca you update question and show me what you have did, coz code which gave you is working fine in my case

Comment: yo can see it here: http://s2.subirimagenes.com/imagen/previo/thump_9020606sin-ttulo.png

Comment: hey where is your class extending AsyncTask<> like i shown you, there you have to override methods

Comment: I must remove the @ override notation? for example:you have wrote  @Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
and i have to write:
protected void onPostExecute(String result)

Comment: dude you are not understanding the code... you are just copying it and pasting

Comment: see. create a class extend it with asynctask and then used my code

Comment: the error you showed me is because you have not created httpAsyncTask class

Comment: i have created httpAsyncTask but not in my activity class, i have two class: activityhttp.class and httpAsyncTask.class

Answer (score 0):

Look at below code for posting data  to php

```
class PlaceOrder extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost httpPst = new HttpPost(

    "http://appdomain.hol.es/webService.php");

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(

    2);
    // add ur parameter here
    parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", value1);
    parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("te", value2);
    httpPst.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));

    HttpResponse httpRes = httpClient.execute(httpPst);



    String str=convertStreamToString(httpRes.getEntity().getContent()).toString();

    Log.i("mlog","outfromurl"+str);


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

    e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

    e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

    e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return null;

    }

    }

    public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;

    try {

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

    sb.append(line + "\n");

    }

    } catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {

    try {

    is.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

    }

    }

    return sb.toString();

    }
```

Comment: outfromurl will tell u output from server u hv got... u can to write this class in ur activity and call it as new PlaceOrder().execute();

Comment: thank you, but i don't understand few things ...

->itemDetails ... where is declarated?
-> Void doInBackground(Void... params) void .. params is correct?

Comment: ok , i will explain you , hv u used asyntask? know abt the concept?

Comment: i've never use asyntask, i know that it is used to do something in background

Comment: cool basically for posting data to server i would suggest u to use asynctask code...see my updated ansere basically the key and value is what i need to pass above

Comment: Thanks, now I see a little more clearly how it works asyntask. 

If you would like to pass values ​​of id and when you do ... that modified the request would have to do?

Comment: m unclear what u said in above comment .."If you would like to pass values ​​of id and when you do ... that modified the request would have to do? "