# AsynTask + Http Post

Tags: android, http, android-asynctask

I have implemented AsyncTask to make http requests to a webService but it gives me an error when I try to get the compiler string returned by the server.

Here's the code of my activity where I think the AsyncTask:

```
public String consultaPreguntaBBDD(int num, String tab)
{
    HttpAsyncTask httpAsyncTask = new HttpAsyncTask(String.valueOf(num),tab);
    /*(!)*/String resul = httpAsyncTask.execute("http://appdomain.hol.es/webService.php");
    return resul;
}
```

Where i've wrote this (!) the compiler says: Type mismatch: cannot convert from AsyncTask to String
and this is the AsyncTask class:

```
class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
{
    private static String id;
    private static String te;
    public  HttpAsyncTask(String id,String te)
    {
            this.id = id;
            this.te = te;
     }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) 
    {
        return POST(urls[0]);
    }
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {

    }

    public static String POST(String url)
    {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";
        try 
        {

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // 2. make POST request to the given URL
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
           // pass parameters in this way

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("te", te));

            //add data
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

            // 9. receive response as inputStream
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            // 10. convert inputstream to string
            if(inputStream != null)
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            else
                result = "Did not work!";

        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
    Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        // 11. return result
        return result;
    }

    private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            result += line;

        inputStream.close();
Log.i("http","result: "+result+"\n");
    return result;
    }
}
```

i have two files, one for each class
can anyone help me? thank's

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android http post + web service PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25117153/android-http-post-web-service-php)

Comment: @jaimin i have duplicated the post for see the problem better

Comment: in stackoverflow you cannot post same question/doubt again else you will be downvoted

Comment: @jaimain sorry, i don't know it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that:

> httpAsyncTask.execute()

returns an instance of itself, which is an `AsyncTask` class. This cannot be converted to a `String`, which is why you get the error.

`.execute` does not return the result of running your `AsyncTask` - it merely starts it. To get the result, you need to access it where it becomes available, once the worker thread has completed its task.

How you should solve it is to fully implement:

> protected void onPostExecute(String result)

in your `AsyncTask` class. The parameter to this function is the result that you are trying to get in the beginning from `.execute`. Here you can safely access it when the result is ready and you can do with it here what you want (call an appropriate function to handle the result, update a textview etc). This is the generel idea behind asynchronous method calls. You don't have the result ***right away***, but when it ***becomes available***.

Comment: So the best solution is to implement the method protected void OnPostExecute (String result), but I can start my AsyncTask activity, and then from the AsyncTask as change objects (variables textview) of another class? I have to put the AsyncTask class within the class of my activity? 

You can use what @jaimin says,and using an object try to synchronize the arrival of AsyncTask with wait and notify?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you ask if you can change e.g. a textview from your AsyncTask class right? if that is what you ask then the answer is: yes you can. AsyncTask has a number of methods, but they run on different threads. onPostExecute runs on the UI thread and can therefore update UI elements directly from there. The easiest way to do this, is to have your AsyncTask be an InnerClass within your Activity, so you can access elements directly. If not, then give your AsyncTask an instance of your Activity when you start it, and make appropriate methods to update it from onPostExecute.

Comment: I watched this video back when I was learning about AsyncTask, so if you can spare 30 mins it is worth watching, as it explains AsyncTask very well, with a nice and simple example. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t988JQHDbX0

Answer (score -1):

edit some code like this

```
public String consultaPreguntaBBDD(int num, String tab)
{
HttpAsyncTask httpAsyncTask = new HttpAsyncTask(String.valueOf(num),tab);
Object resul = httpAsyncTask.execute("http://appdomain.hol.es/webService.php");
return resul.toString();
```

}

httpAsyncTask.execute("http://appdomain.hol.es/webService.php"); is returning a object so change **resul** to objext type and then convert it into string

Comment: This is a problematic solution. This will not give him the result from doInBackground (which is probably what he wants), but rather the string representation of the object thats starts his worker thread. It will solve his compile time error, but not his problem.

Comment: Thanks, but you may want to use when the string in which I transformed the object, the method has not yet finished asynchronous and this is not empty? 
So as said before it is best to create a function and call the asynchronous no class?

Comment: It is best just to call httpAsyncTask.execute(), and not assign the result to any variable. And then you handle the result in onPostExecute in your AsyncTask(). Hope it makes sense.